# Unable to install Aerospike with the default vagrant image

Tags: vagrant, aerospike

It seems there is a problem when configuring the ssh keys when installing Aerospike via the a:

```
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 (guest) => 3000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8081 (guest) => 8081 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: 
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default: 
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of the vagrant image are you using? Are you running it on Mac, linux or Windows?

Answer (score 2):

This may be dependent on your version of vagrant.

Please see

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5059

Suggestion is to add the following to the Vagrantfile

```
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

Vagrant team plan to fix this issue on their next release vagrant 1.8.6

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/4707